# DJango read static file Json

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am learning django, I would like to read a json file but I do not kown where to put it cause I cannot display.

```
I have place the file in the folder "static_project" but it is not working
```

Here is the structure of my project:

```
src=>templates=> Main=> home.html
src=>Myproject=> settings.py
src=>Myproject=>urls.py
```

here the html:

```
{% load static %}
<lottie-player
    src= src="{% static "./myfile.json" %}"  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 700px; height: 700px;"  loop  autoplay >
</lottie-player>
    </div>
```

Hereis the main urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar


    urlpatterns += [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]

    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Here is my setting :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_project")
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "static_root")

#every time a user upload folder, it will be inside the static_cdn  folder and the root "media root"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "media_root")
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Place your static files in the directory provided in `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: I have place the file in the folder "static_project" but it is not working

Comment: Why are you using `./` even if `myfile.json` is in folder `static_project` itself.